# Why is the increment operator used in arrays?

Tags: c

I am pretty knew to C programming and I have been looking through a solution in [leetcode](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-good-pairs/solutions/736026/c/) with this [problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/number-of-good-pairs/description/). I know that the post-increment operator adds by 1 each time for "++", but I am confused with what it would do with the array. What would this do?

My solution for this is...

```
int numIdenticalPairs(int* nums, int numsSize){
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            if (j > i && nums[i] == nums[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

But others I saw wrote it like this with "++" for a[101]

```
int numIdenticalPairs(int* nums, int numsSize){
    int s = 0, a[101] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) s += a[nums[i]]++;
    return s;
}
```

Comment: There's nothing special about an array here. It takes `a[nums[i]]` (the array element) and increments it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            if (j > i && nums[i] == nums[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

This code was poorly written. Since `count` is incremented only if `j > i`, we could write the loop so `j` is always greater than `i`:

```
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < numsSize; j++)
        {
            if (nums[i] == nums[j])
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
```

In contrast, this code:

```
    int s = 0, a[101] = { 0 };
    for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++) s += a[nums[i]]++;
```

seeks to use a cleverer algorithm. `a[nums[i]]++` is parsed as `(a[nums[i]])  ++`. That is, the number in the data array, `nums[i]`, is used as an index into `a`. So there is an element in `a` for each value in `nums`. (For this to work, the values in `nums` must be limited to the valid indices for `a`, 0 to 100, inclusive.)

Then the `++` applies to the element in `a`. `a[nums[i]]++` increments the element of `a` selected by `nums[i]`. So this expression counts the number of times the value `nums[i]` appears.

How does this count matching pairs? When used in an expression, the value produced by `a[nums[i]]++` is the value before it increments the element of `a`. So, the first time it is evaluated for a particular element, it has the value 0, and the element is incremented to 1. The next time, it has the value 1, and the element is incremented to 2.

When there is one instance of a particular value, there are 0 duplicates before it. Call the first instance A. When there is a second instance of the value, say B, there is 1 duplicate before it, so 1 pair is formed, AB. When there is a third instance, C, there are 2 duplicates before it, so 2 more pairs are formed, AC and BC. When there is a fourth instance, D, there are 3 more pairs, AD, BC, and CD. So, when `s += a[nums[i]]++;` is executed, it adds the number of new pairs to `s`.

Thus `s` counts the total number of pairs of values that can be formed from the values in `nums`.

Observe that this loop, `for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)`, goes through the array once. In contrast, in the first code, `for (int i = 0; i < numsSize; i++)` goes through the array once, and the inner loop, `for (int j = 0; j < numsSize; j++)` goes through the entire loop once for each execution of the inner loop. So the total iterations are `numsSize` squared. The second code is much more efficient, if it works (the `nums` values are in bounds).

Answer (score 1):

> "++", but I am confused with what it would do with the array.

```
a[nums[i]]++
```

`++` is not with an *array*.  `++` is with an *array element*.

The `int` value in `a[some_index]` is incremented.